# How to allow bind in app armor?

Tags: 12.04, apparmor, bind

Question:

I did setup bind9 as described here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12149576#post12149576

Now I have a little problem with apparmor: If I switch it off, it works.
If apparmor runs, it doesn't work, and I get the following dmesg output:

```
[   23.809767] type=1400 audit(1344097913.519:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1540 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.811537] type=1400 audit(1344097913.519:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1540 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.812514] type=1400 audit(1344097913.523:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1540 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.821999] type=1400 audit(1344097913.531:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1544 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.845085] type=1400 audit(1344097913.555:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=1543 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.849051] type=1400 audit(1344097913.559:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=1545 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.849509] type=1400 audit(1344097913.559:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=1542 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.851597] type=1400 audit(1344097913.559:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1547 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.415193] type=1400 audit(1344097914.123:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1625 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.738631] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   25.005242] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[   25.187939] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
[   26.004282] Ebtables v2.0 registered
[   26.068783] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   28.158848] postgres (1900): /proc/1900/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1900/oom_score_adj instead.
[   29.840079] xenbr0: no IPv6 routers present
[   31.502916] type=1400 audit(1344097919.088:20): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=1984 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=1989 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[   34.336141] xenbr0: port 1(eth0) entering forwarding state
[   38.424359] Event-channel device installed.
[   38.853077] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state
[   38.854215] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state
[   38.855231] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state
[   38.858891] XENBUS: Unable to read cpu state
[   47.411497] device vif1.0 entered promiscuous mode
[   47.429245] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vif1.0: link is not ready
[   49.366219] virbr0: port 1(vif1.0) entering disabled state
[   49.366705] virbr0: port 1(vif1.0) entering disabled state
[   49.368873] virbr0: mixed no checksumming and other settings.
[   97.273028] type=1400 audit(1344097984.861:21): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3076 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3078 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[  277.790627] type=1400 audit(1344098165.377:22): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3384 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3389 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  287.812986] type=1400 audit(1344098175.401:23): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/root/tmp-gjnX0c0dDa" pid=3400 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  287.818466] type=1400 audit(1344098175.405:24): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/root/tmp-CpOtH52qU5" pid=3400 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  323.166228] type=1400 audit(1344098210.753:25): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3422 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3427 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[  386.512586] type=1400 audit(1344098274.101:26): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3456 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3459 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  808.549049] type=1400 audit(1344098696.137:27): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3872 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3877 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[  894.671081] type=1400 audit(1344098782.257:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3922 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3927 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[  968.514669] type=1400 audit(1344098856.101:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3978 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=3983 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1021.814582] type=1400 audit(1344098909.401:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4010 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4012 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1063.856633] type=1400 audit(1344098951.445:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4041 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4043 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1085.404001] type=1400 audit(1344098972.989:32): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4072 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4077 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1108.207402] type=1400 audit(1344098995.793:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4102 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4107 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1156.947189] type=1400 audit(1344099044.533:34): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4134 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4136 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1166.768005] type=1400 audit(1344099054.353:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4150 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4155 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1168.873385] type=1400 audit(1344099056.461:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4162 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4167 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1181.558946] type=1400 audit(1344099069.145:37): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4177 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4182 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1199.349265] type=1400 audit(1344099086.937:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4191 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4196 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1296.805604] type=1400 audit(1344099184.393:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4232 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4237 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1317.730568] type=1400 audit(1344099205.317:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/tmp-nuBes0IXwi" pid=4251 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1317.730744] type=1400 audit(1344099205.317:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/tmp-ZDJA06ZOkU" pid=4252 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1365.072687] type=1400 audit(1344099252.661:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/tmp-EnsuYUrGOC" pid=4290 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1365.074520] type=1400 audit(1344099252.661:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/tmp-LVCnpWOStP" pid=4287 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1380.336984] type=1400 audit(1344099267.925:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4617 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4622 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1437.924534] type=1400 audit(1344099325.513:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/tmp-Uyf1dHIZUU" pid=4648 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1437.924626] type=1400 audit(1344099325.513:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/tmp-OABXWclII3" pid=4647 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1526.334959] type=1400 audit(1344099413.921:47): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4749 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4754 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1601.292548] type=1400 audit(1344099488.881:48): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4835 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4840 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1639.543733] type=1400 audit(1344099527.129:49): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4905 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4907 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1916.381179] type=1400 audit(1344099803.969:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4959 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4961 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 1940.816898] type=1400 audit(1344099828.405:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=4991 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=4996 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 2043.010898] type=1400 audit(1344099930.597:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=5048 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=5053 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=107 ouid=107
[ 2084.956230] type=1400 audit(1344099972.545:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/tmp-XYgr33RqUt" pid=5069 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 2084.959120] type=1400 audit(1344099972.545:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=3325 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/tmp-vO24RHwL14" pid=5066 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 2088.169500] type=1400 audit(1344099975.757:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" parent=5076 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=5078 comm="named" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 2165.625096] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:56): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.625401] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:57): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.625608] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:58): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.625782] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:59): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.625931] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:60): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.626057] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:61): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.626181] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 2165.626319] type=1400 audit(1344100053.213:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=5124 comm="apparmor"
[ 3709.583927] type=1400 audit(1344101597.169:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=7484 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3709.839895] type=1400 audit(1344101597.425:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=7485 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3710.008892] type=1400 audit(1344101597.597:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=7483 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3710.545232] type=1400 audit(1344101598.133:67): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=7486 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3710.655600] type=1400 audit(1344101598.241:68): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=7481 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3710.656013] type=1400 audit(1344101598.241:69): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=7481 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3710.656786] type=1400 audit(1344101598.245:70): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=7481 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3710.832624] type=1400 audit(1344101598.421:71): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=7488 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3717.573123] type=1400 audit(1344101605.161:72): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=7505 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=7510 comm="named" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=107 ouid=0
[ 3743.667808] type=1400 audit(1344101631.253:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.668338] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.668625] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:75): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.668834] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:76): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.668991] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:77): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.669127] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:78): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.669282] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:79): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3743.669520] type=1400 audit(1344101631.257:80): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=7552 comm="apparmor"
[ 3873.572336] type=1400 audit(1344101761.161:81): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=7722 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3873.826209] type=1400 audit(1344101761.413:82): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=7723 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3873.988181] type=1400 audit(1344101761.577:83): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=7721 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3874.520305] type=1400 audit(1344101762.109:84): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=7719 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3874.520736] type=1400 audit(1344101762.109:85): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=7719 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3874.521000] type=1400 audit(1344101762.109:86): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=7719 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3874.528878] type=1400 audit(1344101762.117:87): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=7724 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3874.930712] type=1400 audit(1344101762.517:88): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=7726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3971.744599] type=1400 audit(1344101859.333:89): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=7899 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3972.009857] type=1400 audit(1344101859.597:90): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=7900 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3972.165297] type=1400 audit(1344101859.753:91): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=7898 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3972.587766] type=1400 audit(1344101860.173:92): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=7901 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3972.847189] type=1400 audit(1344101860.433:93): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=7896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3972.847705] type=1400 audit(1344101860.433:94): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=7896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3972.848150] type=1400 audit(1344101860.433:95): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=7896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3973.147889] type=1400 audit(1344101860.733:96): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=7903 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3988.863999] type=1400 audit(1344101876.449:97): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=7939 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=7944 comm="named" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=107 ouid=0
[ 4025.826132] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:98): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.826627] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:99): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.826861] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:100): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.827059] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:101): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.827214] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:102): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.827352] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:103): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.827485] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:104): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4025.827624] type=1400 audit(1344101913.413:105): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=7975 comm="apparmor"
[ 4027.862198] type=1400 audit(1344101915.449:106): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=8090 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4039.500920] audit_printk_skb: 21 callbacks suppressed
[ 4039.500932] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:114): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.501413] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:115): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.501672] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:116): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.501861] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:117): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.502033] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:118): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.502170] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:119): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.502305] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:120): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4039.502442] type=1400 audit(1344101927.089:121): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=8114 comm="apparmor"
[ 4041.425405] type=1400 audit(1344101929.013:122): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=8240 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4041.425952] type=1400 audit(1344101929.013:123): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=8238 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4058.910390] audit_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
[ 4058.910401] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:130): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.910757] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:131): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.910969] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:132): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.911185] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:133): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.911335] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:134): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.911595] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:135): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.911856] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:136): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/named" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4058.912001] type=1400 audit(1344101946.497:137): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=8264 comm="apparmor"
[ 4060.266700] type=1400 audit(1344101947.853:138): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=8391 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4060.268356] type=1400 audit(1344101947.857:139): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=8391 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 5909.432749] audit_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
[ 5909.432759] type=1400 audit(1344103797.021:146): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=8800 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=8805 comm="named" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=107 ouid=0
root@zotac:~#
```

What can I do that it still works and I don't have to disable apparmor ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
[ 5909.432759] type=1400 audit(1344103797.021:146): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=8800 profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/log/query.log" pid=8805 comm="named" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=107 ouid=0
```

That’s because named isn’t allowed to write to the file `/var/log/query.log`. To solve this issue, open the local include for the apparmor profile of named (`/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named`), add this line:

```
/var/log/query.log rw,
```

Then run

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
```

to reload the profile.

Comment: Someone (check log) edited to point to "/etc/apparmor.d/local" after the answer was accepted.  But "local" doesn't work since apparmor doesn't consider the profile changed ("same as current profile, skipping")

Comment: I've now put the two config lines into /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named and reload worked.

Comment: As Jürgen A. Erhard has commented, this line: ( /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named ), should not have "/local" it it. Can a moderator correct it please. Thanks.

Comment: The above (including "local" works on ubuntu 16.04, but as the README.txt says it depends on there being an "#include ..." in the corresponding non-local file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a line in the file:  /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named

   /var/lib/named/** rw,
2. Run

   sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
3. Run

   sudo systemctl start bind9.service