# Cannot Change Error Log Location For MySQL 5.7 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

Whenever I change the log location

**form:** /var/log/mysql **to:** /var/www

in order to keep every log files in the same place (just under public folder) in mysqld.cnf mysql server cannot restart.

> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
>
> log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql_errors.log

I checked for some solutions and added:

> character-set-server = utf8
>
> collation-server = utf8_general_ci

But still didn't work.
/var/www has 770 permissions and belonging to www-data group.

I added mysql to www-data group:

> sudo usermod -aG www-data mysql

But still didn't work.

MySQL: 5.7.19

Ubuntu: 16.04.1

Here is the error log:

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>
> mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Whenever I undo the log location change, it starts to work.

---

**EDIT 31.07.2017**

I run this after log location change:

```
sudo touch /var/www/mysql_errors.log
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/www/mysql_errors.log
sudo chmod 770 /var/www/mysql_errors.log

sudo systemctl restart mysql

sudo journalctl -xe > ~/journal.txt
```

Here are the relevant log entities:

```
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jul 31 00:33:55 mydomain.com audit[1738]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1738/status" pid=1738 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112

Jul 31 00:33:55 mydomain.com audit[1738]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/www/mysql_errors.log" pid=1738 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="ac" denied_mask="ac" fsuid=112 ouid=112
Jul 31 00:33:55 mydomain.com audit[1738]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" 

Jul 31 00:33:55 mydomain.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you restart your system after adding mysql to group www-data?

Comment: @George Yes, I just restarted and tried again now to make sure but no way...

Comment: Could you post the contents of `journalctl -xe`

Comment: @George Sure I edited my question, please see **EDIT 31.07.2017**

Comment: Can't seem to find any resource on this, have you considered using a symbolic link?

Comment: Yes, I'm temporary using symbolic links. I think the problem is related with **apparmor** disallowing it for some security reasons. I found a solution here: **https://askubuntu.com/questions/172030/how-to-allow-bind-in-app-armor** but looking to see if someone comes up with a solution to specifically address mysql in my case.

Comment: Was able to figure it out please see answer

Comment: Your answer worked perfect, thanks! With your detailed explanations, after understanding how apparmour works in relation to mysql, I get rid of other denial messages I get with **journalctl -xe**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now based on the link you provided and another resource about the relationship between `AppArmor` and `Mysql` I was able to get it to work. The policy that governs mysql is loaded from this location `/usr/sbin/mysqld` which you can see when you run: `sudo aa-status`. This can be altered from,:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

and

```
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

I will be altering the latter.

Steps:

1. I have created a folder `/var/www/html/mysql` and with placed a file (`error.log`) in there. I believe `mysql` will look for such a file. Now this is my custom log location.
2. Open the `/etc/appparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` and add the following lines:

   ```
   /var/www/html/mysql/ r,
   /var/www/html/mysql/** rwk,
   ```

   - Interpretation:

     - `/var/www/html/mysql/ r,`:--> give mysql read access to that folder.
     - `/var/www/html/mysql/** rwk,`:--> give mysql read, write and lock access to contents in there.
3. Open `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and change the log location to:

   ```
   #log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
   log_error = /var/www/html/mysql/error.log
   ```
4. Now restart `apparmor`: `sudo systemctl restart apparmor`
5. Now restart `mysql`: `sudo systemctl restart mysql`

**Note:**

1. I set the user:group of `/var/www/html` to `$USER:www-data` and the permissions to:

   - user: rwx,
   - group: rwx, and
   - others: r-x
2. Added `mysql` user to `www-data` group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G www-data mysql
   ```

Theory:

Apparmor is Ubuntu's way of making sure there is fine grained control over who accesses the file system and how it is done. It has two modes, enforce and complain modes. The enforce mode is where `mysql` falls under ( to see these run `sudo aa-status`).

You can either change `mysql` to `complain mode` where `apparmor` will only complain but not prevent `mysql` accessing other areas of the file system. In this case I choose the `enforce mode` and simply altered the `apparmor` policy for `mysql` To alter these `apparmor` modes you have to install `apparmor-utils` and then you could just do `sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld` and `apparmor` will now only complain about filesystem violations by `mysql`.

Two locations are used to alter the policy, these are (1) `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, and (2)`/etc/appamrmor.d/local/usr/sbin/mysqld`. Which chosen will depend on the type of change desired (network wide or machine specific). So alter to suite your plans.

***Resource(please look at these):***

https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql

https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql

Comment: This worked great thanks! I added these lines to get rid of other DENY messages by apparmour:   /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
  /proc/** r,
  /sys/devices/system/** r,