# How can I move MySQL's default storage location?

Tags: partitioning, mount, mysql

### Background info:

The default installation of MySQL server 8.0 from APT was filling my root partition.

So I recently installed a new drive on my system intended to hold large datasets, including a sizeable MySQL database specifically. I've added the drive to 'fstab', and I've corroborated it gets automatically mounted on start.

### My problem:

I wish to move the default 'datadir' to that mounted drive, but I've had no luck following the [instructions in the original MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html). After I perform the `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/mnt/new_drive` the MySQL error log shows that the created folder is "not usable". I've also attempted the instructions in this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-20-04) and this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnCpDveliUM&t=454s) with no luck.

### Terminal output:

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ sudo chown mysql:mysql /mnt/data/mysql/
(base) ➜  ~ sudo mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql/data
2022-12-05T17:53:54.587829Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) initializing of server in progress as process 31763
2022-12-05T17:53:54.588736Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010174] [Server] Can't change data directory owner to mysql
2022-12-05T17:53:54.588738Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /mnt/data/mysql/data/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2022-12-05T17:53:54.588782Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-12-05T17:53:54.588920Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

### Update 1:

After following steps 1 - 5 as described in the question section of this [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068520/cant-change-data-directory-of-mysql-errcode-13-permission-denied), the `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/mnt/new_drive` step seems to complete successfully. So the permission issues were probably related to AppArmor. But now the server won't start.

The logs in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` show the following:

```sh
2022-12-05T19:42:05.982975Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) initializing of server in progress as process 41772
2022-12-05T19:42:06.022751Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-12-05T19:42:06.164363Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-12-05T19:42:07.137874Z 6 [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: <random password>
```

And this happens when I try to start the MySQL service.

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ sudo service mysql status 
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-12-05 14:46:11 EST; 6s ago
    Process: 42159 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 5ms

Dec 05 14:46:11 Raza systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 05 14:46:11 Raza systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Dec 05 14:46:11 Raza systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 05 14:46:11 Raza systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 05 14:46:11 Raza systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

### System Info:

Ubuntu 22.04
MySQL Server 8.0

Comment: how do you mount the new drive?

Comment: I added an entry with the drive's UUID to the 'fstab' file, similar to how it is described in [this article](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Mount+drive+in+linux+and+set+auto-mount+at+boot).

Comment: Eventually, I identified the issue. Although the official MySQL documentation suggests a command like such as `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql/data/`, I've been specifying `datadir=/mnt/data/mysql/` in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` config file. So for the initialization to go smoothly, I should have used that same data directory `mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql/`.